# Different IP results for ifconfig and socket inet_ntop

Tags: c, linux, bash, sockets, tcp

I am developing an application on Linux. Linux executes the command:

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.10.15 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

at the boot process with systemd.

When I try to learn my ip address with ifconfig here below the result:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:31:E0:44:C6  
          inet addr:192.168.10.15  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:31ff:fee0:44c6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24799 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5475289 (5.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1403459 (1.3 MiB)
```

On the other hand when I try to learn my ip address via program below, I get 192.168.10.42.

```
void GetMyIp(char caIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN])
{
  int s;
  struct ifconf ifconf;
  struct ifreq ifr[50];
  int ifs;
  int i;    

  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (s < 0) 
  {
      #ifdef _DEBUG_PROCESS
        if(EDebugProcess<GetDebugLevelOfPMC())
        {
        PrintToLogFile("Socket error\n");
        }
      #endif
  }

  ifconf.ifc_buf = (char *) ifr;
  ifconf.ifc_len = sizeof ifr;

  if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifconf) == -1) 
  {
    #ifdef _DEBUG_PROCESS
        if(EDebugProcess<GetDebugLevelOfPMC())
        {
        PrintToLogFile("ioctl error\n");
        }
      #endif
  }

  ifs = ifconf.ifc_len / sizeof(ifr[0]);
    struct sockaddr_in *s_in = (struct sockaddr_in *) &ifr[ifs-1].ifr_addr;
    if (!inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s_in->sin_addr, gcaMyIP, sizeof(gcaMyIP))) 
    {
    #ifdef _DEBUG_PROCESS
        if(EDebugProcess<GetDebugLevelOfPMC())
        {
        PrintToLogFile("inet_ntop error\n");
        }
    #endif
    }


    close(s);
    memcpy(caIP,gcaMyIP,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
}
```

What is the source of the difference?

Comment: Have you any other interfaces than eth0? Maybe one of those have IP 192.168.10.42.

Comment: Your error handling is terrible. You do check return values, but don't act upon them. You might be looking at garbage values. But probably you are looking at another interface or possibly an alias of eth0. Why not loop through all interfaces found instead of taking the last one blindly?

Comment: This is an embeedded system runs on linux, not a computer. There is only "ONE" interface. All interfaces should be listed with ifconfig -a and beleive me there is only one interface.

Comment: Embedded implies components may be broken or not implemented correctly.  Contact the embedded system vendor for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that if you want:

http://www.binarytides.com/get-local-ip-in-c-on-linux/